# Fit with function that involves integral

Tags: python, sympy, curve-fitting, integral, symbolic-integration

I am trying to fit a graphic with a function that involves a integral.
If I don't use np.array(), there is a error: "Result from function call is not a proper array of floats."
And if I use np.array(), there is another error: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (501,) and (1,).
How can I fix this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import sympy as sp


x1=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[6,12,18,24,30]


x,a,t=sp.symbols('x a t')

def f(x,a):
    return np.array([sp.integrate(t*x*a,(t,0,2))],dtype=float)

xFit=np.arange(0,5.01,0.01)
popt, pcov=curve_fit(f,x1,y)
plt.scatter(x1,y)
plt.plot(xFit,f(xFit,*popt),color="r")
print(popt[0])
```

Comment: For your amusement: `f(xFit, *popt)` returns `array([1.17145785e+146])`

Answer (score 0):

The function `f(x,a)` expects scalar arguments, and returns a scalar value even if `x` is a vector.  Try replacing your `plot()` line with this:

```
ystar = [f(_x, popt[0]) for _x in xFit]
plt.plot(xFit, ystar, color="r")
```

Comment: that worked! thank you! but there is still a problem: the value of popt [0] returned by the program is 0.22277227722772278, but it should be 3

Comment: gotta admit I'm baffled by the curve fitting.  `f` takes two parameters but I don't see where `a` is specified.  There may be a crossed wire between the function's input parameters and the `ydata` to fit.

Answer (score 0):

well... it seems to me that this resolved:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import sympy as sp


x1=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[6,12,18,24,30]


x,a,t=sp.symbols('x, a, t', real=True)
g=sp.integrate(t*x*a,(t,0,2))
f=sp.lambdify((x,a),g)

xFit=np.arange(0,5.01,0.01)
popt, pcov=curve_fit(f,x1,y)
plt.scatter(x1,y)
ystar = [f(_x, popt[0]) for _x in xFit]
plt.plot(xFit, ystar, color="r")
print(popt[0])
```

Comment: Remember to use comments and explicit variable names. You won't remember what is `popt` when you return to that project in a few weeks.

Comment: @Guimoute in general this is true, however for optimal parameters `popt` would be quite common...